# Tab doesn't auto complete on user "minecraft" but completes with root

Tags: auto-completion

On my user "minecraft" whenever I hit the tab key it just indents instead of auto completing. It works fine on root though.

Output of `getent passwd minecraft`:

```
minecraft:x:1001:1001::/home/minecraft:/bin/sh
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail?

Comment: You must provide more information. Please [edit] your question to include the output of `getent passwd minecraft` (assuming *minecraft* is your username). Also, you could run `source /etc/bash_completion` then check if autocompletion works.

Comment: I edited my post and did the other thing you said it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you change your shell from `sh` to `bash`:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash $USER
```

Also, make sure you have the default initialization files in your home directory:

```
cp /etc/skel/{.bash*,.profile} $HOME
```